# How do I debug the output of a method in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Post model class, I'm trying to debug the following code:

```
after_create :transcode_video, :if => "is_video? && !Rails.env.development?"

def is_video?
  return false unless post_link
  link_extension = post_link.downcase.split(".").last
  VIDEO_FORMATS.include? link_extension
end
```

I want to output a debug string to check the value of `is_video`.

I tried adding

```
after_create logger.debug "#{is_video}"
```

and

```
after_create logger.debug "#{is_video?}"
```

but get a routing error in each case.  I also tried using "puts" instead of logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing this in a method rather than in one line.

Something like:

```
class MyClass

    after_create :log_is_video

    ...

    private

    def log_is_video
      logger.debug "#{is_video?}"
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked.  I'm guessing the ? isn't necessary at the end of the log_is_video method, right?

Comment: Nope. You can name the method whatever you wish. :)